# CancellationToken doesn't propagate

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to create a function that would trigger on certain event after N seconds. If same event would appear again previously scheduled execution should be canceled and new one is supposed to be scheduled.

I tried to model this behavior through following code:

```cs
class Trend<T>
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken =
        new CancellationTokenSource();

    public void AddObservation(T observation)
    {
        // I don't really care about T.
        //
        Func<CancellationToken, T, Task> action =
            async (CancellationToken token, T obs) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), token);
                if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} Task executed {obs}");
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
            }
        };

        // cancel previos execution, if any.
        cancellationToken.Cancel();

        // create new token
        cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Run(async () => await action(cancellationToken.Token, observation));
    }
}
```

Simple test:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Trend<int> trend = new Trend<int>();

    // Schedule 10K tasks
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        trend.AddObservation(i);
    }

    // Only the last one should execute.
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000));
}
```

My expectation would be to have only the last observation executed upon and all the others canceled. In reality not a single task got canceled.

Now, what worked was to create a list of cancellationtokens and keep a reference to each one of them:

```cs
private List<CancellationTokenSource> cancellationTokens =
    new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
...
    foreach (var ct in cancellationTokens)
    {
        ct.Cancel();
    }

    CancellationTokenSource c = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationTokens.Add(c);

    Task.Run(async () => await action(c.Token, observation));
```

Rough assumption is that garbage collector is cleaning CancellationTokenSource and thus nullifying the effect of Cancel call.

I don't know much about async internals so help would be appriciated.

Comment: IMO it is better to catch `OperationCanceledException`, because some operations throw that on cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Because all tasks are using same `CancellationToken`.

You can check by changing your code to this:

**(This code is just for testing. Answer is below of this Code)**

```
class Trend<T>
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public void AddObservation(T observation)
        {
            // I don't really care about T.
            //
            Func<CancellationToken, T, Task> action = async (CancellationToken token, T obs) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), token);
                    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} Task executed {obs} TOKEN IS {token.GetHashCode()}" );
                    }
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                }
            };

            // cancel previos execution, if any.
            cancellationToken.Cancel();

            // create new token
            cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.WriteLine($"TOKEN CREATED {cancellationToken.Token.GetHashCode()}");

            Task.Run(async () => await action(cancellationToken.Token, observation));
        }

    }
```

**But why?**

when you run `Task.Run(async () => await action(cancellationToken.Token, observation));` you are scheduling a `Task` that will start another task which is `action` here.
so before all task get start and call `action`, `cancellationToken` refrence to the last created one so all `Task`s will call action by **last created** `CancellationToken`.

**Solution**

Just simply call `action(cancellationToken.Token, observation);` instead of `Task.Run(...)`; so your action will call with **current** created `CancellationToken`.

**Solution Complete Code**

```
class Trend<T>
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public void AddObservation(T observation)
    {
        // I don't really care about T.
        //
        Func<CancellationToken, T, Task> action = async (CancellationToken token, T obs) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), token);
                if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} Task executed {obs}");
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
            }
        };

        // cancel previos execution, if any.
        cancellationToken.Cancel();

        // create new token
        cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        action(cancellationToken.Token, observation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. This `Trend` implementation accepts a synchronous or asynchronous action, and can be rescheduled multiple times. It exploits the
existing functionality of the `CancellationTokenSource` class (the [`CancelAfter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter) method).

```
class Trend : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new();
    private readonly Task _task;

    public Task Completion => _task;

    public Trend(Action action) // Synchronous delegate
    {
        _task = Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, _cts.Token).ContinueWith(
            _ => action(), TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public Trend(Func<Task> action) // Asynchronous delegate
    {
        _task = Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, _cts.Token).ContinueWith(
            _ => action(), TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the action is scheduled successfully for future execution.
    /// Returns false if the action is already running or it has completed.
    /// </summary>
    public bool StartAfter(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested) return false;
        _cts.CancelAfter(delay);
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _cts.Dispose();
}
```

Usage example:

```
var trend = new Trend(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Action!");
});
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Scheduling trend...");
    trend.StartAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
}
await trend.Completion;
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Finished");
```

Output:

```
04:39:06.541 Scheduling trend...
04:39:06.669 Scheduling trend...
04:39:06.771 Scheduling trend...
04:39:06.872 Scheduling trend...
04:39:06.990 Scheduling trend...
04:39:07.104 Scheduling trend...
04:39:07.205 Scheduling trend...
04:39:07.306 Scheduling trend...
04:39:07.408 Scheduling trend...
04:39:07.512 Scheduling trend...
04:39:08.027 Action!
04:39:08.027 Finished
```